# Javascript compilation in Ruby on Rails 6

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ecmascript-6, webpacker

I'm using RoR 6.1.0, and would like to add a Javascript library. As a test case, I'll try to add JQuery. I am using webpacker to manage the Javascript libraries in my app.

First I use *yarn* to add jquery to the project:

```
yarn add jquery
```

Next I import *jquery* in the webpacker application entry point, `app/javascript/packs/application.js`. The second line verifies the import:

```
import jQuery from "jquery";
console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery);
```

My custom javascript files are saved in `app/asets/javascripts`. I create the file `app/assets/javascripts/test.js` as:

```
import jQuery from "jquery";

function test() {
    console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery)
}
```

Finally, in my view, I include `test.js` and assign the function to a button:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag('test.js') %>
<button onclick="test()">Button</button>
```

On page load, the console displays the following error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`. I think this means the file `test.js` is not being processed by the ES6 compiler. How can I make sure that the javascript files in `app/assets/javascript` are compiled properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `webpacker` and you want to include js files in your views/layouts then you have to use [javascript_pack_tag](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/webpacker/Webpacker%2FHelper:javascript_pack_tag). All these files (called `entries`) should be under `/packs` (or where you set the `source_path` & `source_entry_path` in your `webpacker.yml`). The entries should import or require different files (bundle them) then webpacker will prepare them to be browser ready (babel, loaders, transpiling, etc..)

Create `app/javascript/packs/test.js` and add these:

```
 require('app/assets/javascripts/test.js')
```

This should fix the complilation issue. Webpacker has `resolved_paths: []` in `webpacaker.yml` where you can add different paths to look for files. You can add `app/assets/javascripts` and change to:

```
require('test.js')
```

Now clicking that button. If you want to do it that way then `test()` should be on `window`. Another option is to bind an onClick event for that button at document ready. There are other options but these 2 are the easy ones.

Comment: Yes this makes sense! Since the webpacker entry point is `app/javascript/packs`, I've moved all my javascript there, and removed it from `app/assets/javascripts`. Changing the AssetTagHelper from `javascript_include_tag` to `javascript_pack_tag` did the trick. Thank you!